# UI Pattern for loading images from a background thread

Tags: android

I have code that reloads images via HTTP from the main thread and displays them, right after setting up the layout.

This is now deprecated since network access must no longer be done from the main thread.

At first, I changed it to load the images from a a background thread and then update the ImageViews. But, the user experience changed since the images now "pop out."

Is it possible to make the images load seamlessly?
Or, should I display a progress bar or status message while the images reload.

Comment: use AsyncTask and do your stuff in onBackground(), you can use progressbar also in this....

Comment: You should look into [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Thanks RajaReddy and aneal. I know it can be done, I'm asking if it's a good idea UI-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seamless loading would require to delay to display your entire ui which is probably not what you want. You could use an animation to fade in your images once they are loaded.